# How to uninstall screen (monitor / display) drivers?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, uninstall, cat, inf

While testing out some different computer screens (also called displays or monitors) on a Windows 7 SP1 system, I installed the .INF files for each screen.  I also installed the .ICM (color matching profile) for each screen.  Furthermore, several of them included .CAT (digital signature catalog) files.

Not that it's required, but to keep things tidy, how does one uninstall each of these three types of files?

Comment: Win 7 is bloated with drivers for hardware you don't own.  These are a drop in the bucket and the files are small.  Is it really worth the time?  Just askin'.  :-)

Comment: It's not worth the time in regards to space occupied on fixed storage. It *is* worth the time in regards to keeping the system tidy in order to keep it properly maintained and running smoothly.